# Geoserver - HTTP ERROR 503

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

Can you please help with removing this error ... after adding a new community module I restarted geoserver and I cannot load geoserver home page. I have added mbtiles for correct version of geoserver (2.10.1). I also try start geoserver service manually but not works.

Error message:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /geoserver/web/. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
```

Error log:

```
2017-01-19 23:03:19,404 INFO [config.XMLFileResourceProvider] - Will look for geowebcache.xml in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\data_dir\gwc'
2017-01-19 23:03:19,419 INFO [config.XMLFileResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2017-01-19 23:03:19,419 INFO [config.XMLFileResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2017-01-19 23:03:19,419 INFO [config.XMLFileResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
2017-01-19 23:03:19,482 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
2017-01-19 23:03:19,482 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
2017-01-19 23:03:19,482 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
2017-01-19 23:03:19,482 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
2017-01-19 23:03:19,671 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
2017-01-19 23:03:19,672 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
2017-01-19 23:03:19,675 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
2017-01-19 23:03:19,931 INFO [gwc.layer] - GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog loaded successfuly
2017-01-19 23:03:19,931 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc
2017-01-19 23:03:19,931 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc
2017-01-19 23:03:19,931 INFO [layer.TileLayerDispatcher] - Configuration gwc contained no layers.
2017-01-19 23:03:19,946 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
2017-01-19 23:03:19,946 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\data_dir, using it as the default prefix. ***
2017-01-19 23:03:19,946 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
2017-01-19 23:03:20,015 INFO [config.XMLFileResourceProvider] - Will look for geowebcache.xml in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\data_dir\gwc'
2017-01-19 23:03:20,031 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2017-01-19 23:03:20,046 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
2017-01-19 23:03:20,046 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
2017-01-19 23:03:20,046 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas. 
2017-01-19 23:03:20,068 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 29 layers attached to global quota 500,0 MB
2017-01-19 23:03:20,100 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
2017-01-19 23:03:20,348 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl-1e93b72a:159b8c1699b:-8000', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,361 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wcs', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,378 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,412 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,438 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl-5678044c:159b17bed69:-5844', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,447 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WCSInfoImpl-5678044c:159b17bed69:-5843', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,472 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WFSInfoImpl-5678044c:159b17bed69:-5842', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,480 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMSInfoImpl-5678044c:159b17bed69:-5841', enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:20,525 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
2017-01-19 23:03:20,796 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/gwc/service/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-01-19 23:03:20,848 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
2017-01-19 23:03:20,879 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
2017-01-19 23:03:20,879 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
2017-01-19 23:03:20,942 INFO [rest.RESTDispatcher] - Created RESTDispatcher with 15 paths
2017-01-19 23:03:20,973 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
2017-01-19 23:03:20,973 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
2017-01-19 23:03:21,004 INFO [config.XMLFileResourceProvider] - Will look for geowebcache.xml in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\data_dir\gwc'
2017-01-19 23:03:21,879 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-01-19 23:03:21,879 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/*] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-01-19 23:03:21,879 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/kml/icon/**/*] onto handler 'kmlIconService'
2017-01-19 23:03:21,957 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows/**] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-01-19 23:03:21,957 INFO [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/ows] onto handler 'dispatcher'
2017-01-19 23:03:21,957 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 WARN [support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbtilesProcess' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.10.1/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-mbtiles-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wpsResourceManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wpsResourceManager' is defined
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - destroy() invoked
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - GeoWebCacheDispatcher.destroy() was invoked, shutting down.
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota monitor shutting down...
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [diskquota.QuotaUpdatesMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota statistics gathering monitor...
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [diskquota.QueuedQuotaUpdatesConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to InterruptedException
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [diskquota.QueuedUsageStatsConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to interrupted exception
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Initiating shut down for running and pending seed tasks...
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Seeder thread pool executor shut down complete.
2017-01-19 23:03:22,004 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageBroker] - Destroying StorageBroker
2017-01-19 23:03:22,020 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'geoWebCacheExtensions': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2017-01-19 23:03:22,020 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbtilesProcess' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.10.1/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-mbtiles-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wpsResourceManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wpsResourceManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wpsResourceManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you access the server? You may get some info by checking the logs.

Logs are in the GeoServer data directory, or if you're using Tomcat, you  can look at the catalina.out file.

Since it says 'service unavailable', you could check your tomcat is running, or go to the root (so without /geoserver).

Perhaps update your question more information about your environment, too.

EDIT:

Note the error message `"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbtilesProcess' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.10.1/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-mbtiles-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wpsResourceManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wpsResourceManager' is defined"`

This indicates that the WPS extension isn't installed.

Comment: I've updated question, check please

Comment: Have you installed the WPS extension?

Comment: That's good news!